# Is there a generic algorithm to put a list of sorted integers into buckets?

Tags: python, algorithm

How do you filter integers 1-52 into 13 buckets? [1 to 4], [5 to 8], [9 to 12], etc. I want to know if given 2 random integers are they in the same bucket? I have tried

```
(X mod 4) - X]
```

but get the wrong results below.

```
#first bucket
(1 mod 4) - 1 = 0
(2 mod 4) - 2 = 0
(3 mod 4) - 3 = 0
(4 mod 4) - 4 = -4 #wrong result

#2nd bucket
(5 mod 4) - 5 = -4
(6 mod 4) - 6 = -4
(7 mod 4) - 7 = -4
(8 mod 4) - 8 = -8 #wrong result
```

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: The ring starts at 0, not 1, so you need: `((x-1) mod 4) - (x-1)`

Comment: Thank you! So simple in hindsight. You are my savior.

Answer (score 1):

As the numbers start with 1, subtract 1 first. And then you don't need to use the modulo operator. Instead use integer division, and you'll get a sequence number for a "bucket" (0..12):

```
def bucketof(a):
    return (a - 1) // 4


print(bucketof(5) == bucketof(8))  # True
```